# SMTP Timeout. Using our own server and swiftmailer. How can I increase the timeout? Error included

Tags: php, smtp, timeout, swiftmailer

I'm looping through a list of customers, and sending files to them. The page often times out. Here is the exact error generated, minus my domain name.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Connection to smtp.example.com:25 Timed Out' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inc\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:169 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inc\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(400): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->readLine(67)
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inc\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(277): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_getFullResponse(67) 
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inc\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(245): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('??.??', Array, Array) 
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inc\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(335): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('??.??', Array) 
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inc\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(428): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_streamMessage(Object(Swift_Message)) 
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inc\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(444): Swift_Tra in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inc\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 169
```

I'm not sure if this is PHP timeout, or some sort of SMTP server timeout.

If this is PHP, I can try to increase my timeout there. I have tried adding 
`set_time_limit (0);` to the top of my .php file, but that didn't help, should I be adding that to the function itself as the first line?

Comment: This post is similar, but the answer there doesn't help me.

Comment: looks like swiftmailer is causing that, so changing core php settings won't matter, because swift's setting the timeout itself on the fsockopen() call

Comment: @Marc B This solution looks promising, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257114/how-to-close-smtp-connection-in-swiftmailer?rq=1 but they don't include sample placement. I tried it, but it didn't work where I put it (just before and after the send command).

Comment: i have this problem too after sending a few thousand emails, even though i use the throttle and anti flood plugins...

Answer (score 3):

I just posted a working solution to your (our!) problem on [How to close Smtp connection in SwiftMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257114/how-to-close-smtp-connection-in-swiftmailer?rq=1) 
tell me if it works for you as well.
Cheers